# Detecting End of Animation

Tags: iphone, animation, objective-c

So I am making a death animation for a game. enemy1 is a UIImageView, and what I'm doing is when an integer is less than or equal to zero, it calls this deathAnimation which only happens once. What I want to do is use a CGPointMake right when the animation is finished being called. Note that before the deathAnimation is called, there is another animation that is constantly being called 30 times a second. I'm not using anything like cocos2d.

```
if (enemy1health <= 0) {
    [self slime1DeathAnimation];
    //How can i detect the end of this animation
}
```

This is how the animation is done:

```
-(void)slime1DeathAnimation{
    enemy1.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slime Death 1.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slime Death 2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slime Death 3.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slime Death 4.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slime Death 5.png"],
                              nil];
    enemy1.animationDuration = 0.5;
    enemy1.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [enemy1 startAnimating];
}
```

If you need more code just ask

Answer (score 2):

If you are animating the views using CoreAnimation, then you can set a method as callback that will be invoked after the animation is over using the following method:

```
[+ (void)setAnimationDidStopSelector:(SEL)selector][1]
```

More details on how the animation is done could help to answer your question right.

Comment: i've edited the post

Answer (score 0):

In your case the best way to go would be to set the `animationDuration` and `animationRepeatCount` property of the `UIImageView` and then schedule a timer to call a selector method just after calling `startAnimating` with the same delay as the duration of animation.

```
enemy1.animationDuration = 0.5;
enemy1.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[enemy1 startAnimating];
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(somemethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Also you can stop the animation for the enemy1 object in that `somemethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Use +animateWithDuration:animations:completion: (available on iOS 4+), you will have a completion block.
Something like :

```
[UIVIew animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
    enemy1.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slime Death 1.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slime Death 2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slime Death 3.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slime Death 4.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Slime Death 5.png"],
                              nil];
}
                  completion: ^(BOOL finished){
   // Your animation is finished
}];
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This code is doing nothing!